Using an If statement in a Dax measure
I am wanting to write a measure which will allow me to do 3 different sums depending on what string is found in a column. For example imagine a nutrition table of which we will focus on two columns. the first column has the labels, Protein, Carbs, and Fat. The second column has a numerical value in grams. I want to use a measure (not a calculated column as I will have other factors which make me need to use a measure) in order to calculate calories in each.
I had hoped something along the lines of
‘Nutrition’[Grams] * (IF([Macro]=“Protein”, 4), IF([Macro]=“Carb”, 4), IF([Macro]=“Fat”, 9)  

Would work

I am aware that formatting is wrong but the error I am running into is that I can’t use an if statement with a string at al

I think the problem here is that you're trying to refer directly to the value of a column in a measure, which isn't allowed (you could read about row context in this article which might help explain why it doesn't work).
To reference the Macro column in an IF function in a measure you can use a function which creates a row context.  Here's a basic example of a measure using the SUMX function which gives you the results that (I think) you want:
Calories = SUMX(
    Nutrition,
    Nutrition[Grams] * IF(
        Nutrition[Macro] = "Fat",
        9,
        4
    )
)

This produces results like this when added to a table visual:
Results of measure using SUMX
I hope it helps but let me know if not!

Refer to the SWITCH function.
  var x = SWITCH([Macro], "Protein", 4, "Carb", 4, "Fat", 9)
  return 'Nutrition[Grams] * x

